# Is it possible to redirect React app users from 127.0.0.1:3000 to localhost:3000?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React application with other developers who regularly navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` to view/use the app. When accessing the app via `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` it is partially functional, which is causing confusion. Is it possible to redirect users from `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` to `http://localhost:3000/`? It seems like the `<Route />` component from `react-router-dom` only deals with (as the name implies) the app route (and not the domain/port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Place it in your app component and it will monitor the web address and check whether it includes `127.0.0.1:3000`. If so, it will redirect to your `localhost`.

```
if (window.location.href.includes("127.0.0.1:3000"){
  window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/")
}
```

Even better, if you wanted to maintain the page the user is currently on, just replace `127.0.0.1:3000` for `localhost:3000`:

```
const currentDomain = window.location.href
 
if (currentDomain.includes("127.0.0.1:3000"){
  newDomain = currentDomain.replace("127.0.0.1:3000", "localhost:3000")
  window.location.replace(newDomain)
}
```